# On Ubuntu 12.04, is there any tools to check what programs are connecting to other NFS server share?

Tags: 12.04

There are some programs running in the client, so I want to check what programs are using files or connecting to the server. To be safety, I want to check this at first before I shutdown the server. Yes, I use the unmount to disconnect to the server NFSserver. But if some programs in the client is dependent on the files in the server,I think they will be get the wrong results. So I ask for help that if there exists some commands about this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check what programs are actively accessing a network resource using the `fuser` and `lsof` commands.  Assuming your NFS share is mounted at /mnt/nfs, you could use either of the following commands to look for processes accessing the share:

```
lsof -Pni
```

or

```
fuser -m /mnt/nfs
```

The `fuser` option will give you a list of process IDs that are accessing the mount point specified with the -m option.  You can add the `-k` option to terminate those processes automatically.

With the `lsof` option, you will have to look for the IP address of the server in the last column.  The name of the process will be in the first column.  You may want to stick with `fuser`.

Comment: Thanks, sir. I have typed the `fuser -m /media/server_nfs_share` on the client `Ubuntu 12.04`, but it shows nothing. And before this, I have opened a file on the `/media/server_nfs_share` on the client `Ubuntu 12.04`. I don't know which is wrong. And `lsof -Pni` will show some connection information, but it still doesn't show which client is connecting to the server, I think the client `Ubuntu 12.04` should be showing. Anything wrong?

Comment: The `fuser` command will only show commands with active connections. If a client has read data but does not have any active locks, etc, the network connection can be closed. To demonstrate, run `vim /mnt/server_nfs_share/some_file.txt` and then `fuser` in another terminal. Shows nothing. Then make some modifications in the vim window and without saving run `fuser` again. This time you will see a process ID. The `fuser` command for this example should be run from the client.